# How to normalize for loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop

I really want to know how to normalize for loops . In other words , I want to change for loops

from

```
for (i = k; i <= n; i += c) // k>=0 n>=0 c>0
```

to

```
for (j = 0; j <= itNumber-1; j++) // itNumber is the number of iterations
```

How to find `itNumber = f ( n , k , c )` ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Are i, k, n and c integers?

Comment: Based on information you post, `itNumber` can be 73... what are you doing? What is input/output?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock yes integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to find:

You are looking for a transformation that will give you a "canonical" loop, starting from zero and increments the iterator by 1 in each step.

First of all, lets offset the loop `for (i = k; i <= n; i += c)`, such that `i` will start from `0`: `for (i = 0; i <= n - k; i += c)`, and for each **read** occurrence of `i` inside the loop do `i:=i+k`. (you can't optimize in that method if `i` is written inside the loop)

Now let's handle the jumping gaps. currently, `i` is incremented by `c` each iteration, so we have to divide by `c` in order to increment in `1`: `for (i = 0; i <= (n - k)/c; i += 1)`, and for each **read** occurrence of `i` inside the loop do `i:=i*c`.

For some reason you are asking for a base case `i<=itNumber-1`, so we got `i <= (n - k)/c + 1 - 1`, and we can summarize:

**transformation of the condition:
`f(n, k, c) = (n - k)/c + 1`**

**and the transformation for `i` inside the loop is: `g(i) = c*(i+k)`**

**the calculations are between integers** (like in 'C'), so `x/y` is actually the integer part of it: `floor(x/y)`

Comment: That's great , but i think it last something , how about if `(n-k)/c+1` is not interger ??  In that case , we probably consider `f(n,k,c)=E((n-k)/c+1)` which `E is the integer part` . @avim What do you think ??

Comment: @Mallek I forgot to mention, I am taking about integers, and divition of integers, so yes, you should take the integer part

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I finally understand :).

Well I think that it should be the difference between k and n divided by increment, therefore

```
itNumber = (n-k)/c
```

Comment: No, it's `(n-k+1)/c`.   If you need the old index `i`, use `i=j*c + k`.

Comment: @user1016274 , @libik  i think both of you are wrong . It may be `((n-k)/c)+1`

Comment: what about using of the iterator inside the loop? and he ask "how to find", not "what is"